# Odd error message from ftp connecting on port 22

Tags: ftp

I am a little confused. I am trying to FTP using port 22. It says that I am connected, then that I am not connected. Here is my output:

```
dan@voldemort:~$ ftp $hname 22
Connected to <hostname>.

SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
ftp> ls
Not connected.
```

What's going on?

Comment: might not be ***logged in on*** the FTP server. did you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a response from the SSH server, which listens on port 22.  FTP servers usually listen on port 21.